# Java generics - iterating through list of uninstantiated classes extending from same parent and call parent method

Tags: java, android, class, generics, gson

I have a list of classes with extend a base class

```
public class Entity{
abstract String getTitle();
}
```

The child classes are

```
public class ChildEntityOne extends Entity{

    public static final String TITLE= "ABCD";

    @Override
    public String getTitle() {
        return TITLE;;
    }

}
public class ChildEntityTwo extends Entity{

    public static final String TITLE= "EFGH";

    @Override
    public String getTitle() {
        return TITLE;;
    }

}
public class ChildEntityThree extends Entity{

    public static final String TITLE= "WXYZ";

    @Override
    public String getTitle() {
        return TITLE;;
    }
}
```

now i'm trying to pass a list of valid classes to a function
which creates an instance from one of the classes from list and returns it

```
    List<?ClassesToChooseFrom?> list = new ArrayList()<>;
    list.add(?ChildEntityOne?);
    list.add(?ChildEntityTwo?);
    
    Entity result = getInstantiatedClass(list,getKey(),getjsonData())
    if(result instanceof ChildEntityOne){
     //do something
    }else if(result instanceof ChildEntityTwo){
     //do somwthing
    }
    
    
    public ?InstantiatedClassObject? getInstantiatedClass(List<?ClassesToChooseFrom?> list,String key,String jsonData){
      foreach(?Class? itemclass : list){
         if(itemClass.getTitle().equals(key)){
return new GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(jsonData, itemClass);}
    }
    return null;
    }
```

Ive tried
**List<Class<? extends Entity>> classes = new ArrayList<>();**

but unable to go further..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the beginning right: a list of subclasses of Entity is:

```
    List<Class<? extends Entity>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(ChildEntityOne.class);
    list.add(ChildEntityTwo.class);
```

Then you just need to make `getInstantiatedClass` use the same types you pass to it:

```
public Entity getInstantiatedClass(List<Class<? extends Entity>> list, String key, String jsonData) {
    for (Class<? extends Entity> itemclass : list) {
        if (getTitle(itemClass).equals(key)) {
           ...
```

You could make that generic, if you don't want to/need to do anything special for the Entity class.

```
public <T> T getInstantiatedClass(List<Class<? extends T>> list, String key, String jsonData) {
    for (Class<? extends T> itemclass : list) {
        ...
```

To extract the value of the static `TITLE` field from a child entity class you can use:

```
private String getTitle(Class<?> itemclass) {
    try {
        return (String) itemclass.getField("TITLE").get(null);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException | NoSuchFieldException e) {
        return "N/A";
    }
}
```

Comment: This is only the half correct implementation. I cannot itemClass.getTitle() in foreach loop

Comment: There is no `getTitle()` method in `Class`. I don't know what you want to compare with. Perhaps you want `getName()` or `getSimpleName()`? The methods that are available for Class are listed in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html

Comment: Ohh I see your "child entity" classes each have a TITLE field, is that what you want to compare with?

Comment: Yes.I want to compare the key with list of classes which have their own unique titles